# APP_INITIALIZER is not working in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, es6-promise

I need to load configuration from service at the Angular initial level.
So, For demo I have created **boot module**, **boot class** and load APP_INITIALIZER from the Angular core into the boot module.

Check the following file, I not able see the **console.log("Init Function works")** as well as **console.log("GET CONFIG WORKS")**

Please correct me if anything wrong.

// Module file
**boot.modue.ts**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Boot, Config, Menu } from './../../core/classes';
import { MenusService } from './../services/';

export function init(_boot: Boot) {
  console.log("Init Function works");
  return () => {
    return _boot.getConfig();
  };
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [Boot,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
      useFactory: init, 
      deps: [Boot], multi: true 
    }]
})

export class BootModule {
  constructor() { }
}
```

// Class file
**boot.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export class Boot {
    /**
     * getConfig
     */
    public getConfig(): Promise<any> {
        console.log("getConfig");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("GET CONFIG WORKS");
                resolve();
            }, 3000);
        });
    }

    /**
     * initMenus
     */
    public initMenus() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you defined an `init` function and referenced an `init1`

Comment: Apart from `init1`, I don't see why this shouldn't work. Are you able to replicate the problem in plunker or stackblitz?

Comment: init1 has mystically happened when adding a question on StackOverflow, Actually, its init and have checked this on local but not work, even not able to see the console messages.

Comment: Ok, I will check this on stackblitz and same here.

Comment: What you have seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fz99h8?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Just to add on `getConfig` method return type of method Promise<any> should be changed to Promise<void> but as what @David said this examples works perfectly.